# Access denied to cloudfront distribution s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I'm uploading a website to S3 which I configured to be accessed via a cloudfront distribution. When I access the distribution URL through in the browser I get:

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>TKHNQGGSSHY3ZH6T</RequestId>
   <HostId>zXD7uBIpJUGHaUl8m5/9xtm2cnvX/Kok6rYp0oz6RFbqJeLreohaOWHx4jHJ/F675UGxo1SfEYs= 
   </HostId>
</Error>
```

This is my sam cloudformation tempalte snippet, I'm guessing there's some issue with the StockMonitorFeBucketPolicy.

```
##################### FRONTEND

  StockMonitorFeBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      BucketName: osotnikov-stock-monitor-front-end-resources-s3-bucket
      AccessControl: Private
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
  StockMonitorFeBucketDistributionOriginAccessIdentity:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity'
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: This is the origin access identity (simply user).
  StockMonitorFeBucketDistribution:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'
    DependsOn:
      - StockMonitorFeBucket
      - StockMonitorFeBucketDistributionOriginAccessIdentity
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !GetAtt
              - StockMonitorFeBucket
              - DomainName
            Id: StockMonitorFeBucketCloudFrontOrigin
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub >-
                origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${StockMonitorFeBucketDistributionOriginAccessIdentity}
        Enabled: 'true'
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          TargetOriginId: StockMonitorFeBucketCloudFrontOrigin
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: 'false'
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
  StockMonitorFeBucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    DependsOn:
      - StockMonitorFeBucket
      - StockMonitorFeBucketDistributionOriginAccessIdentity
      - StockMonitorFeBucketDistribution
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref StockMonitorFeBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: cloudFrontReadAccess
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              CanonicalUser: !GetAtt
                - StockMonitorFeBucketDistributionOriginAccessIdentity
                - S3CanonicalUserId
            Action: 's3:GetObject'
            Resource: >-
              arn:aws:s3:::osotnikov-stock-monitor-front-end-resources-s3-bucket/*
```

This is the bucket policy that it added after deployment:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "cloudFrontReadAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E1V8NTQPK5FD7P"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::osotnikov-stock-monitor-front-end-resources-s3-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Alternatively I try:

```
Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref StockMonitorFeBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: cloudFrontReadAccess
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Join
                - ' '
                - - 'arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity'
                - - !GetAtt [ StockMonitorFeBucketDistributionOriginAccessIdentity, S3CanonicalUserId ]
            Action: 's3:GetObject'
            Resource: >-
              arn:aws:s3:::osotnikov-stock-monitor-front-end-resources-s3-bucket/*
```

But then I get:

```
 a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.
```

I tried to change the principal to

```
Principal: AWS: !Join [' ', ['arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity', !GetAtt [StockMonitorFeBucketDistributionOriginAccessIdentity, S3CanonicalUserId]]]
```

But I get Invalid principal in policy error

Comment: Can you share what bucket policy it added after deployment in AWS console?

Comment: Policy seems ok to me. Just to confirm,  Do you have index.html file in the root of the bucket?

Comment: yes I have many files as well as index.html

Comment: I tried to change the principal to 
```
 Principal:
              AWS: !Join [' ', ['arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity', !GetAtt [StockMonitorFeBucketDistributionOriginAccessIdentity, S3CanonicalUserId]]]
```
But I get Invalid principal in policy  error

Comment: Can you try accessing a file other than index.html by providing the direct path? ex: https://d1abc1ab111111.cloudfront.net/testfile.txt

Comment: ye just tried that still the same, also tried deleting it and uploading a dummy one, same result

Comment: @user11666461 It can't be any name. It does not have to be logical id of any resource.

Answer (score 0):

There is **nothing wrong** with your template (I deployed it). It works as expected. The only way to get `AccessDenied` in your case is due to lack of [DefaultRootObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-distributionconfig.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-distributionconfig-defaultrootobject) as `index.html` defined. Thus you have to explicitly add `index.html` to your cloudfront url, e.g.:

```
http://21342sfssgdf.cloudfront.net/index.html
```

Comment: I tried that multiple times, didn't work in my case

Comment: @Bat0u89 This means that your real template is different than in the question, or your question does not provide full information reflecting your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the Principal to

```
CanonicalUser: !GetAtt StockMonitorFeBucketDistributionOriginAccessIdentity.S3CanonicalUserId
```

and it worked ... maybe it's because I'm using sam idk